# How to add custom field in email header using Message class in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to send an email with a custom header that contains the following fields,

From:

To:

RT: (my custom field)

Below is my code

```
public Message createHeader(InternetAddress from, Address to, Address rt) throws MessagingException {
    Message m = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
    m.setFrom(from);
    m.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    // add my custom filed "RT:"+rt
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setHeader()](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/1.6/apidocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setHeader-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

You can read the description:

> Set the value for this header_name. Replaces all existing header
> values with this new value. Note that RFC 822 headers must contain
> only US-ASCII characters, so a header that contains non US-ASCII
> characters must have been encoded by the caller as per the rules of
> RFC 2047.

And your code will be something like:

```
public Message createHeader(InternetAddress from, Address to, Address rt) throws MessagingException {
    Message m = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
    m.setFrom(from);
    m.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    m.setHeader("RT", rt.toString());
    return m;
}
```